# Do I have to manually input the values of my hash table into my code or can I read them from a text file

Tags: c++, database, data-structures, hashtable

I'm trying to create a hash table to perform constant time look up on a set of values with over 1000 entries. My idea of the function is to split each of them into groups of 26 based on the initial letter, then have a formula for getting a hash function inside each of the letter buckets. For example, if the value is "StackOverflow", it would input it in bucket "S" or "19", and in bucket S, there would probably be about 50 buckets. Then it would perform the hash function, maybe get bucket 34, and input the value in bucket 34.

My question is, I have a text file with all 1000 values. Do I have to manually type them into my code, making sure to put them in their correct buckets, or is there a way I can avoid this? My friend said I should use a map, but I feel hash tables should be able to do this and I'm just too inexperienced to understand.

Comment: *Do I have to manually type them into my code, making sure to put them in their correct buckets* -- I don't quite understand.  Your hash table class doesn't have a method to add an item?  If so, just call `AddItem()` or whatever it is called with the data from the file in some sort of file reading `for` loop.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie But won't whatever I add get deleted once I restart the program?

Comment: The file is not deleted -- it's still there.  Or does it flame out like in the Mission Impossible movies?  Your program will just read the file at startup and populate the table.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm a little bit confused, because I have to initialize the arrays while I restart the program, doesn't that set everything to its default state?

Comment: So are you writing the data to a file before the program exits?

Comment: I want to but that's where my question lies. I don't know how to write it in a way that it matches the structure of my hash table, as my hash table is an array of array of structures. Is there a way for me to write that into a file and read from that file in constant time in the same structure I coded my program in?

Comment: Don't bother having a hash table for each initial letter: just use `std::unordered_set<std::string>` or `std::unordered_map<std::string, some_other_type>` if you're trying to associate values of `some_other_type` with each key.  When you `insert` values, it will work out which buckets to use all by itself.